# Laravel artisan migrate deployment production

Tags: php, laravel, jenkins, deployment, laravel-5.3

In my deployment strategy I want to do the following:

1. Get code from git
2. Install dependencies via composer (dev requirements as well)
3. Run tests (phpunit etc)
4. Install dependencies for production  (will remove dev requirements)
5. Zip
6. Copy to server
7. Unzip
8. Change symlink to current release (leave 2 old releases in case of revert)

At this point can I run `php artisan migrate` to update the database?

Considerations:

The application cache files are purged (actually they are empty like a fresh install).
Will the migrate query check the schema to know if updates are required?

**All in all**:

Can I run `php artisan migrate` safely in production with no previous application cache?

How does the `migrate` task kow the history of the table and what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first run your migrations, Laravel creates a `migrations` table which helps it to know at what point you are with your migrations.

I suggest doing **always** a backup, anyway you can update your tables without any issue if you test them locally before applying them in production and, most important, you don't edit the old migrations but instead add new ones to migrate, event to edit existing tables (add/remove columns).

PS: Why would you need to symlink if you use git? I'd just tag a working release.
If you are able to get ssh access to your hosting server, even a sandboxed version to just be able to access your site folder, you may directly deploy using git. Best way to avoid any problem caused by a failing copy of files.

Comment: Oh damn, you are right, thank you for pointing this out. I am currently working on migrating from zend 2 and didn't set-up the migrations table. Looked in anothe project, thank you!

Comment: I use symlink because I have 3 other projects which have this strategy and wanted to maintain consistency, again thanks, happy coding :)

Comment: Good luck, take care ;)